# Maximum capacity of a Thunderbird account?

Tags: thunderbird, email-client

I know someone who has lots of emails in a Thunderbird account. One day Thunderbird stopped receiving emails and asks the user to either delete or compress old emails to make more space. Unfortunately, due to the large number of incoming emails Thunderbird got "full" again.

So, is there a cap on the size of a Thunderbird account? Is there a way to lift the cap? There is still a lot of room left on the hard drive.

Comment: How many emails was it? I had 30,000 with no issues

Comment: David Allen's GTD Method may be of interest to you. I save emails as files that need to be stored, otherwise they are deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a limit of 4GB (in some instances, only 2GB) on a folder:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Limits_-_Thunderbird#Folders_and_messages

There is apparently no way to lift the cap other than to "configure the mail directories and/or the Local Folders directory to be stored outside of the profile", as in the link.